# How to get the length of each word in a column without AWK, sed or a loop?

Tags: bash

Is it even possible? I currently have a one-liner to count the number of words in a file. If I output what I currently have it looks like this:

```
3 abcdef
3 abcd
3 fec
2 abc
```

This is all done in 1 line without loops and I was thinking if I could add a column with length of each word in a column. I was thinking I could use `wc -m` to count the characters, but I don't know if I can do that without a loop?

As seen in the title, no AWK, sed, perl.. Just good old bash.

What I want:

```
3 abcdef 6
3 abcd 4
3 fec 3
2 abc 3
```

Where the last column is length of each word.

Comment: Thought of `expr length WORD` for using shell builtin only and not calling out for `wc`?

Comment: doesn't `wc -m` also count `\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read -r num word; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$num" "$word" "${#word}"
done < file
```

Comment: I like this solution better than mine. It's more elegant.

Comment: Though `awk '{print $1, $2, length($2)} file'` will run much faster.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein That wouldn't work for inputs with spaces: `1 hello world` -> `1 hello 5` but should be `1 hello world 11`

Comment: @andlrc Can be easily fixed if OP wants this behavior. From the question I understood that he/she's asking for a single word size. Thanks for emphasizing this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this also:

**File**

```
> cat test.txt

3 abcdef
3 abcd
3 fec
2 abc
```

**Bash script**

```
> cat test.txt.sh

#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  items=($line) # split the line
  strlen=${#items[1]} # get the 2nd item's length
  echo $line $strlen # print the line and the length
done < test.txt
```

**Results**

```
> bash test.txt.sh

3 abcdef 6
3 abcd 4
3 fec 3
2 abc 3
```